# Netbeans Module: open JFrame on button click

Tags: java, netbeans, module, jframe

I am coding a module for Netbeans where I have a button that when clicked will open a JFrame.

This is the action listener class of the button:

```
// ... (package and imports)

@ActionID(
        category = "File",
        id = "org.myorg.readabilitychecker.ReadabilityActionListener"
)
@ActionRegistration(
        iconBase = "org/myorg/readabilitychecker/google.png",
        displayName = "#CTL_ReadabilityActionListener"
)
@ActionReference(path = "Toolbars/File", position = 0)
@Messages("CTL_ReadabilityActionListener=Readability")
public final class ReadabilityActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFrame readabilityFrame = new ReadabilityFrame();
        readabilityFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

In the JFrame I basically have:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ReadabilityFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

It also has some other automatically generated code, but nothing important.

When I run the application, the button appears in the toolbar, but when I click it, the JFrame doesn't open.

I tried checking if a print inside the `actionPerformed()` method would show in the output terminal and it does, so I guess that I am missing something while calling the JFrame.

Can anyone give me a hint on where the problem is?

Comment: Have you coded fully or just right click and added a frame and in button click you written the code? Or coded everything manually?

Comment: "or just right click and added a frame and in button click you written the code" - I did this. While debugging, I noticed that when I try to call ReadabilityFrame readabilityFrame = new ReadabilityFrame(); it call the method initCompnents() that has this line "setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);". Here, it gives a exception "Variable information not available, source compiled without -g option" and stops the execution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the object creation of your frame. Try

```
 ReadabilityFrame readabilityFrame = new ReadabilityFrame();
 readabilityFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem persists after changing the previous code with this one.

Answer (score 0):

I found where was the problem.

The method initComponents() automatically generated had the line `setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` and it was always throwing an exception.

I just changed `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` to `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`, defined the frame in a different way and now, the problem disappeared.